# incorrect keyboard input language on lubuntu login

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, login, password, keyboard-layout

I've set a password on my Lubuntu in Persian language without any problem but when i shutdown the PC and tried to sign in for the first time i could not to change the language to Persian it was only US English.
and please consider that I've stuck on login page and I'm posting my question from a live Lubuntu which is on my flash and the mentioned OS is lubuntu 19.04 desktop version 64-bit.
I'll be appreciative if you answer my question as soon as is possible.

Comment: Please provide release details (are you using LXDE or LXQt, which greeter... release details answer these questions).

Comment: I dont know about what you said but I think its LXQT

Comment: Lubuntu and Ubuntu 19.04 are EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  You need to upgrade first to a supported release of Ubuntu/Lubuntu (ie. 19.10).

Comment: In your case, I'd just start again installing the Lubuntu 19.10 system.   I do recall issues with other languages on 19.04, but no longer remember fixes.. They didn't occur with 19.10 though (and 19.10 provides an easy path to upgrade to 20.04 LTS very soon..)

Comment: is there any other solution rather than reinstalling

Comment: Your system is *end-of-life* thus now off-topic as no longer supported.  You'll have to *release-upgrade* as soon as you login anyway, which will take longer than a re-install.  Yes there were fixes, but 19.04 is now off-topic (due to EOL status; we don't want to encourage use of unsupported, or un-patched systems) so you'll encounter other issues as well thus re-install is the fastest & easiest by far.   The manual if wanted can be viewed at http://manual.lubuntu.me/